# Query to match different values in one column that have same value in a separate column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that will take two different values in column b and then compare it with column c to determine if the two values in column b share the same value in Column C. However i also need column A in the output as well.

For example

```
Column A         Column B        Column C
Test 1           x               12345
Test 2           y               12345
Test 3`          A               12344
Test 4           D               12342
```

Desired Output

```
Column A        Column B        Column C
Test 1           x              12345
Test 2           y              12345
```

Any help would be great

Comment: I should have been more specific column b has many many values. I want to query to determine if if x and y specifically ever have the same value in column c

Comment: This question is asked soooo often

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the values in `ColumnB` are significant. This query finds values of `ColumnC` that are repeated and then returns those rows:

```
select * from T where ColumnC in (
    select ColumnC from T
    group by ColumnC
    having count(*) > 1 /* or maybe count(distinct ColumnB) > 1 */
)
```

Comment: I should have been more specific column b has many many values. I want to query to determine if if x and y specifically ever have the same value in column c

Comment: The thing that isn't clear is whether x could ever be equal to y. The query should do what you want. If you do need to also check for unequal x and y then you might want to try the `count(distinct ...)` add left in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `JOIN` like below. See a demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da525/4

```
select t.*
from tbl1 t join tbl1 s on t.`Column C` = s.`Column C`
and t.`Column B` <> s.`Column B`;
```

(OR) Using `WHERE EXISTS`

```
select t.*
from tbl1 t
where exists ( select 1 from tbl1 
              where `Column C` = t.`Column C`
              and `Column B` <> t.`Column B`);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a join table b on a.c=b.c and a.b<>b.b
```

The query doesn't take into account rows that have same values in c and b column.
You can add `DISTINCT` in the select if needed.